# Lining up candies

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking one way to do it was to use stars and bars on the pink and green candies, but I don’t really know what to do.

Comment: Convince yourself that you must have three blocks of one color and two blocks of the other.  You can use stars and bars to find the number of ways to do this.

Comment: Have you tried implementing Ross's hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have either $PGPGP$ or $GPGPG$. There are $6$ P's and $8$ G's.

Form the partitions into $2$ or $3$ parts ([]) and the number of ways to do this (()):

**Pink**
$[1,5](2), [2,4](2), [3,3](1)$
$[1,1,4](3), [1,2,3](6), [2,2,2](1)$

**Green**
$[1,7]](2), [2,6](2), [3,5](2), [4,4](1)$
$[1,1,6](3), [1,2,5](6), [1,3,4](6), [2,2,4](3), [2,3,3](3)$

The answer is then two pinks $\times$ three greens $+$ three pinks $\times$ two greens, or:

$(2+2+1)(3+6+6+3+3)+(3+6+1)(2+2+2+1)=5\cdot21+10\cdot7=175$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the stars as the pink candies and the dot as the green candies and we place the bars to separate 2 candies of the different types

- There are exactly 4 bars drawn
- The starting candy and the final candy (leftmost and rightmost) must be of the same type because there are 4, which is an even number of switching points where the color of the candies change.

Because of the the switch points mentioned above, there are two cases as below:

Case I: Pink candy first,
so there are 2 groups of green candies and 3 groups of pink candies. Thus we have $\binom{5}{2}*\binom{7}{1}=70$ ways

Case I: Green candy first,
so there are 3 groups of green candies and 2 groups of pink candies. Thus we have $\binom{7}{2}*\binom{5}{1}=105$ ways

In total, there are $70+105=175$ such ways to organize this

### **EDITS**

And it was carried out in the form of star and bar of the Euler's candy division problem.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Have this new solution satisfied the problem. I am wondering why my number now is way too small. At least the number of places for the 4 bars has been $\binom{13}{4}=715$. But again I feel this too large to be true. Can you please point out my fault?

Comment: The choices of how many green candies are in each run (consecutive candies of the same color) and how many pink candies are in each run are independent.  Therefore, you should be multiplying rather than adding in each case.

Comment: But again I think that the independent cases must be added rather than multiplied. Dependent cases must be multiplied.

Comment: The [Multiplication Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) states that if one task can be performed in $m$ ways and another task can be performed in $n$ ways, then there are $mn$ ways of performing both tasks.  We [add](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) when two tasks are mutually exclusive.  Choosing how many pink candies are in a run can be determined independently of how many green candies are in a run.  Therefore, we multiply within each case.  Since the two cases are mutually exclusive, we add their results.

Comment: And yes, I did so, and the result yields 43

Comment: What I meant was you should have $\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{1} + \binom{7}{2}\binom{5}{1} = 70 + 105 = 175$.